# My java calculator project has errors. I don't know how to fix them

Tags: java, android-studio, calculator

I had a calculator app to do as a project and I'm a bit lost. My teacher only put the java text itself, but there's some elements in the xml document that I need to add.

Here is some problems with my main document. My onClickfunctions are underlined as unused.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView _screen;
private String display="";
private String currentOperator="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _screen=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    _screen.setText(display);
}
private void updateScreen() {
    _screen.setText(display);
}
private void **onClickNumber**(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    display+=b.getText();
    updateScreen();
}
public void onClickOperator(View v) {
    Button b= (Button) v;
    display+=b.getText();
    currentOperator=b.getText().toString();
    updateScreen();
}
private double operateArithmetic(String a, String b, String op) {
    switch (op) {
        case "+": return(Double.valueOf(a) + Double.valueOf(b));
        case "-": return(Double.valueOf(a) - Double.valueOf(b));
        case "x": return(Double.valueOf(a) * Double.valueOf(b));
        case "\u00f7": try{
            return(Double.valueOf(a) / Double.valueOf(b));
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Calc", e.getMessage());
        }
        default: return -1;
    }

}

private double operateTrigonometric(String a, String op) {
    switch (op){
        case "sin": return(Math.sin(Double.valueOf(a)));
        case "cos": return(Math.cos(Double.valueOf(a)));
        case "tan": try{
            return(Math.tan(Double.valueOf(a)));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Calc", e.getMessage());
        }
        case "\u221a": return(Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(a)));
        default: return -1;
    }
}
public void **onClickEqual**(View v) {
    String[] operation=display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperator));
    Double result;
    if(operation.length==1) {
        result = operateTrigonometric(operation[0], currentOperator);
        _screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
    }

    else if (operation.length<2)
        return;

    else {
        return = operateArithmetic(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperator);
        _screen.setText(display + "\n" + String.valueOf(result));
    }
}
private void clear() {
    display="";
    currentOperator="";
}
public void **onClickClear**(View v){
    clear();
    updateScreen();
}
```

What is in double * are the things that appear grey. (I am using Android Studio)

My buttons have nothing special, only Layout properties to them.
My teacher noted that I need to add an OnClickNumber to my xml file (with all the buttons) and the only option I have is to add

```
android:onClick="onClickfunction"
```

the function is either Operator, Clear or Equal.

when actually running the app I get an error message for line

**return = operateArithmetic(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperator);**

because I'm expected to add something before the =

Comment: **Daniels ???**

Comment: I'm  sorry? ?? I don't understand

Comment: Should it be `result = operateArithmetic(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperator);`  How can you assign anything to `return` keyword?